# rtweet Advanced Streaming Questions

Tags: r, rtweet

I am new to the `rtweet` package and have versions of the same question related to queries passed to `POST statuses/filter.`

Per [Twitter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/filter-realtime/api-reference/post-statuses-filter), "The default access level allows up to 400 track keywords, 5,000 follow userids and 25 0.1-360 degree location boxes."  **Does `stream_tweets` follow this structure?  For example, could I pass 200 keywords and 300 user IDs and 2 bounding boxes?  If yes, how does `stream_tweets` know which parts of the passed vector are keywords, user IDs, and bounding boxes?**

The documentation of `stream_tweets`, for example, says that a bounding box "must be provided via a vector of length 4, e.g., c(-125, 26, -65, 49)".  I interpret this meaning only one bounding box per connection, which is less functionality than `POST statuses/filter` allows.  Same if `stream_tweets` does not distinguish between user IDs and keywords.  I believe I would just pass everything as part of one long character vector, e.g. 'car,table,box,3892190,38901930,-74,40,-73,41' would give tweets with any of those 3 words, from any of the 2 users, or from within that last bounding box.